# Virtual KVM "Mouse Without Borders" Fails During Logon Password Prompt, UAC Prompts

Tags: remote-access, kvm-switch

I've been using Microsoft Garage Band's free ["Mouse Without Borders"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/wall-of-fame/mouse-without-borders/) (MWB) successfully to control multiple Windows 10 PCs with the physical keyboard and mouse that's closest to me at the moment; I can glide the mouse into any of the other PC's screens easily, all done via software. But I find that,

- Whenever I have to login to a PC and input a PIN or password, I lose MWB's functionality and have to resort to typing in that PIN or password directly using the target PC's own physical keyboard.
- MWB also temporarily becomes useless if a User Account Control (UAC) prompt appears, such as when I right-click on the CMD command prompt icon and request to "Run as administrator"--I have to use the target's PC own physical mouse to click Yes at the Yes/No UAC prompt (you know, when it asks, "Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?").

Is there a way to make MWB continue to work under these circumstances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to enable MWB for the target PC's Administrator user. To do so, you must first enable that user on Windows 10 by executing the command "net user administrator /active:yes" from an elevated command prompt. You can then login to it (it has no password initially), run MWB on it, and then make sure MWB has the same security key string as the source PC from which you want to control it. You may then logoff the Administrator account (I recommend you put a password on it prior to logging off). Once you log back in as your regular user account, UAC prompts and password login screens won't disable MWB anymore!